# How to make a function that picks according to a changing distribution, without passing over and over?

Tags: matlab, math, random

This is not a question about MatLab, but it is a question about how to achieve something that would be easy in object-oriented programming when you're using a less sophisticated language.

I'm a mathematician who is writing some MatLab code to test an algorithm in linear algebra (I won't burden you with the details). The beginning of the program is to generate a random 500 by 50 matrix of floats (call it A). In the course of running my program, I will want to pick random rows of A, not uniformly at random, but rather according to a distribution where the likelihood of row i being picked is different, depending on the specific matrix that has been generated.

I want to write a function called "pickRandomRow" that I can call over and over when I need it. It will use the same probability distribution on the rows throughout each individual run of the program, but that distribution will change between runs of the program (because the random matrix will be different).

If I were using a more object-oriented language than MatLab, I would make a class called "rowPicker" which could be initialized with the information about the specific random matrix I'm using on this run. But here, I'm not sure how to make a function in MatLab that can know the information it needs to know about the random matrix A once and for all, without passing A to the function over and over (expensively), when it's not changing.

Possible options

- Make `pickRandomRow` a script instead of a function, so it can see the workspace. Then I wouldn't be able to give `pickRandomRow` any arguments, but so far I don't see why I'd need to.
- Start messing areound with classes in MatLab.

Comment: MATLAB is object oriented now. C can be as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this task you could use the [randsample function](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) and, to be exact, its four arguments overload:

> y = randsample(n,k,true,w) or y = randsample(population,k,true,w)
>   returns a weighted sample taken with replacement, using a vector of
>   positive weights w, whose length is n. The probability that the
>   integer i is selected for an entry of y is w(i)/sum(w). Usually, w is
>   a vector of probabilities. randsample does not support weighted
>   sampling without replacement.

An example:

```
M = [
  1 1 1;
  2 2 2;
  3 3 3;
  4 4 4;
  5 5 5
];

idx = randsample(1:5,1,true,[0.2 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4]);
row = M(idx,:);
```

If you have to pick more than one row every time you run the script and the fact that the weighted sampling without replacement is not supported, you could use the [datasample function](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) instead:

```
M = [
  1 1 1;
  2 2 2;
  3 3 3;
  4 4 4;
  5 5 5
];

idx = datasample(1:5,2,'Replace',false,'Weights',[0.2 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.4]);
rows = M(idx,:);
```

For what concerns the choice between a class and a script, I honestly think you are overcomplicating your problem a little bit. An OOP class, in this case, looks like an overkill to me. If you want to use a script (actually, a function) without passing any argument to it, you could use the [persistent modifier](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) on an internally defined matrix and a variable representing its row probabilities. Let's assume that the first solution I proposed is the one that fits your need, then:

```
a = pickRandomRow();
b = pickRandomRow();
c = pickRandomRow();

function row = pickRandomRow()
    persistent M;
    persistent W;

    if (isempty(M))
        M = [
          1 1 1;
          2 2 2;
          3 3 3;
          4 4 4;
          5 5 5
        ];

        W = [
          0.2
          0.2
          0.1
          0.1
          0.4
        ];
    end

    idx = randsample(1:size(M,1),1,true,W);
    row = M(idx,:);
end
```

If you want to provide different weights according to previous computations, you could change the above code as follows:

```
w1 = WeightsFromDistributionX();
w2 = WeightsFromDistributionY();

a = pickRandomRow(w1);
b = pickRandomRow(w2);
c = pickRandomRow(w2);

function row = pickRandomRow(W)
    persistent M;

    if (isempty(M))
        M = [
          1 1 1;
          2 2 2;
          3 3 3;
          4 4 4;
          5 5 5
        ];
    end

    M_size = size(M,1);
    W_size = numel(W);

    if (M_size ~= W_size)
        error('The weights vector must have the same length of matrix rows.');
    end

    idx = randsample(1:M_size,1,true,W);
    row = M(idx,:);
end
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. Advantages/disadvantages between making the matrix persistent vs. global? By the way, I am already using datasample. Great minds think alike...

Comment: Heheh thanks! Actually, persistent allows a variable to persist only within the scope in which it has been declared. Unless you want to display your matrix or have any sort of control over it, I think persistent is more appropriate in this case. Also, global has a performance drawback (the in-memory location of the variable must be found every time the function is called)... but I think it would have a minor impact in this case.

Comment: I think I want the main function to generate the matrix, though, not rowPicker. Certainly I want the main function to see the matrix. Really I want to communicate the necessary information about the matrix to rowPicker once and for all, and then just have it return row numbers to me when I need them. Maybe just make global the relevant info about the matrix?

Comment: Yes you can totally do this. But at that point, if this doesn't bother you, it's better to pass the matrix as an argument. As I previously specified, the global keyword has a problem: every time it's invoked (in this case, every time your row picking function is called), Matlab has to "search" the in-memory location of the variable... and this impacts the performance. In this case it's absolutely fine, but avoid abusing this feature for future reference, especially within complex frameworks.

Comment: Gotcha. So passing the (large) matrix as an argument many times would likely present less of a cost than the 'global' cost? Or maybe hard to tell in such generality as I've asked my question? Thanks for helping me learn about this

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, MATLAB supports closures.
Closures are something like an object with bunch of private member variables and a single method.
So, you could do something like this:

```
function rowPicker = createRowPicker(matrix, param)
  expensivePreparations = ... (use 'matrix' and 'param' here) ...
  function pickedRow = someComplicatedSamplingFunction
    ... (use 'matrix', 'expensivePreparations' and 'param' here) ...
  end 
  rowPicker = @someComplicatedSamplingFunction
end
```

and then you could generate a bunch of differently parameterized `rowPicker`s in a loop, something like this:

```
for p = [p1, p2, p3]
  matrix = generateMatrix()
  picker = createRowPicker(matrix, p)
  ... (run expensive simulation, reuse 'picker')
end
```

In this way, the expensive intermediate result `expensivePreparations` will be saved inside the closure, and you won't have to recompute it in each step of your `expensive simulation`.

Warning: all of the above it matlab-esque pseudocode and not tested.

Comment: Interesting idea. I've never used lambdas this way in MATLAB, but I think it could work.

Answer (score 0):

If creating a class is too much work (you first class will be, it's quite different than in other languages), you have several alternatives.

**A single distribution at the time**

You can accomplish this using `persistent` variables in a function. The function will become some sort of unique object.

```
function out = func(arg)
persistent M; % matrix to pick rows from
persistent S; % status
if nargin == 1
  M = randn(...);
  S = ...;
else
  % use M, S
  return ...;
end
```

You call this using `func('init')` the first time,  and `data = func()` after that.

**Multiple different distributions**

You can rewrite the above but returning a cell array with the internal data when called with `'init'`. Other times you pass that cell array as input:

```
function out = func(arg)
if ischar(arg)
  M = randn(...);
  S = ...;
  return {M,S};
else % iscell(arg)
  % use M=arg{1}, S=arg{2}
  return ...;
end
```

Of course, instead of a cell array it could be a struct. I see this as a "poor man's object". There's no control over the user modifying the status of the object, but if you're your own user, this is probably not a big deal.